# PDF icon removed from TEMPLATES but still appearing in libraries

Tags: 2010, pdf, file-icons

We have a request to add the PDF icon to SharePoint. 
Because of our change process I have to first make this change in our dev environment. 
The only problem is that it has already been done in the dev, by someone else. 
I want to remove it from the dev so that I can redo it and the change can be approved. 
I have deleted the icpng.gif from TEMPLATES/IMAGES and removed the necessary line from the XML. 
After restarting the IIS the icon for pdfs is still showing in libraries. 
Any ideas as to why this may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you perform these steps on each web front end? I'm guessing it's cached somewhere. Try rebooting the server(s). Try clearing the cache in your browser.

HTH